# Sort TreeMap based on own rule

Tags: java, android, sorting, sharedpreferences, treemap

I've a `TreeMap` and I want to sort the keys based on my own rule. This is how I get the keys:

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs2",
                    MODE_PRIVATE);
TreeMap<String, ?> keys = new TreeMap<String, Object>(pref.getAll());
```

As you can see I get the keys from `SharedPreferences`. The keys come in the following order: `Yesterday`, `Older`, `Today`.

I want the following order from `Today` to `Older`. So: `Today`, `Yesterday`, `Older`.

I've tried something like this:

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs2",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
TreeMap<String, ?> keys = new TreeMap<String, Object>(pref.getAll()) {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // Here the return based on our own rule
    }
};
```

But I don't know how to define that rule and I'm not sure if I correctly use the `compare function`.

Is is possible to sort the `TreeMap` on the rule as I described above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely possible to do what you're describing, but you need a `Comparator`, instead of overriding anything in `TreeMap`

```
Comparator<String> sortByPreferenceKey = new Comparator<String>(){
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // Put your comparison logic here
    }
};
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs2", MODE_PRIVATE);
TreeMap<String, Object> keys = new TreeMap<String, Object>(sortByPreferenceKey);
keys.putAll(pref.getAll());
```

Comment: I'll get this error: `The constructor TreeMap<String,Object>(Map<String,capture#1-of ?>, Comparator<String>) is undefined` on the line where `new TreeMap` is called.

Comment: My apologies.  For some reason, I thought `TreeMap` had a constructor that it didn't.  I have edited my answer; please try again.

Comment: Thanks! For the compare I use this: `final List<String> definedOrder = Arrays.asList("Today", "Yesterday", "Older");` and in the compare function: `return Integer.valueOf(definedOrder.indexOf(o1)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(definedOrder.indexOf(o2)));`

Answer (score 1):

No.

`TreeMap` does not rely in a `compare` method (neither it does implement `Comparable`).

Instead, define a `Comparator<String>` subclass (it can be an anonymous class) and implement your `compare` method there (RaptorDotCpp description is good, but you can also READ THE JAVADOC which explains this and lots of other things).

Pass an instance of your `Comparator` in the `TreeMap` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookup table in your Comparator.

```
Map<String,Integer> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put( "Today", 1 );
// etc

public int compare( String o1, String o2 ) {
    Integer q1 = values.get( o1 );
    Integer q2 = values.get( o2 );
    return q1.compareTo( q2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that a `TreeMap` does not have a `compare` method. However, you can create a subclass of `Comparator` and pass it to the constructor of your map.

The `compare` method should return a negative number if `o1` is smaller than `o2`, a positive number if `o1` is greater than `o2` and 0 if they are equal.

You can write the method as such:

```
public int compare (String o1, String o2) {
    if("Yesterday".equals(o1) && "Older".equals(o2)) {
        return 1; // o1 > o2 => positive number
    }
    // etcetera
}
```

Note that you don't need to write an `if` statement for every possibility: take the following example.

```
if("Today".equals(o1) && !"Today".equals(o2)) {
    // The first String equals "Today" (the greatest possible value
    // And the second doesn't. This means the second must be smaller.
    return 1;
}
```